# Extending Android Classes In Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

From what I can tell, Eclipse only supports making "skeleton-code" for very few class extensions in Android (such as `Activity`).  If I want to extend `TextView`, `Fragment`, etc. I have to start completely from scratch and provide my *own* skeleton code.

Is that true, or am I missing something simple in Eclipse that creates skeleton code for various class extensions?

Comment: skeleton-code? You mean overriden methods?

Comment: What do you mean by skeleton code ? If you want to extend an Android class just do it, then add your own methods or redefine existing ones.
When extending a View class you are not forced to redefine all its methods, of course. Maybe onMeasure() and onDraw(), at least. See official website for more informations.

Comment: By skeleton code, I meant overridden, empty methods, like you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by skeleton code you mean overriding the methods in the super class, then try the following:

In the package explorer, right click on the class, go to the `Source` tab and select `Override/Implement Methods...`. This will give a list of the methods you can override and implement.

Alternatively, go to a new line in the class editor outside of an existing method and press `control + space` to bring up a list of methods you can override. This is faster when overriding only one or two methods.

Comment: Oh okay, this makes it easier to discover what methods can even be overridden, which I suppose was the issue I was trying to solve.  As a new Android developer, I have no idea what can be overridden in many of the classes.  control + space is really useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between `Activity` or `TextView` when creating a new class from the Eclipse wizard.

By default all methods that need to be implemented will be auto-generated (constructors, abstract methods, interfaces' methods)

Answer (score 1):

Say you class extends TextView.

Eclipse will ask you to override certain required methods in your class.

If you want to override some additional methods.
Right Click on the class name `TextView`. Goto Source and select `Override/Implement methods`. Then select the methods you want to override in your own class.